# Facebook SDK Manifest Issue: Unity3d

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using facebook package 4.3.6 for sharing post from my unitygame..

Now My sample sdk run properly with my AppID..

but as per my game requirement, i need to change in Manifest file..

This is SDK manifest file block :

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
</activity>
```

Now change is that : i want to make UnityPlayerActivity as main launcher activity.. if i make it as launcher activity then fb login not working..

This change i want to make for other requirement of my game..

Please solve my this problem..

Help me guys.. Thanks to everyone for supporting me and helping me till now..

Comment: I cant use fb sdk with other plugins.. :(((

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need FBUnityPlayerActivity for the Facebook stuff to work.  You can extend the activity class to put in the other requirements of your game instead of extending UnityPlayerActivity.

Answer (score 0):

We have new v5.0.2 beta version of the SDK which should play nice with other plugins.

Check Brian's answer in this thread [How to work with Facebook SDK for Unity and Vuforia for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928723/how-to-work-with-facebook-sdk-for-unity-and-vuforia-for-android)